# Loading .js files using javascript in synchronous manner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to include multiple js files in synchronous manner and once they are successfully included I will call `function main()` which will create the widget. For that currently I have built a function this way

```
var scriptArrayHC = [retrieveURL()+"/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                    "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js",
                    retrieveURL()+"/js/html5shiv-2.js",
                    retrieveURL()+"/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js",
                    retrieveURL()+"/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"];
function loadScript(scriptArray, func){
    var counter_script=0;
    [].forEach.call(scriptArray, function(src){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = function() {
            counter_script++;
            //console.log("Script "+counter_script+" --- "+src);
            if(counter_script==scriptArray.length) eval(func);
        };
        script.src = src;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    });
}

loadScript(scriptArray, "main()");
```

It is working fine.. But i think it is not the best way. Does anyone have a better way to do this or is there any library for this?

Comment: Why not dynamic asynchronous loading (require/browserify/webpack/jspm/whatnot)?

Comment: Have a dig through RequireJS on [git](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs).  While it loads js _async_, it does appear to append scripts into the header and may not be far off what you're trying to achieve - have a look around the code, I'm sure they've got close to what's the _best way_.

Comment: Will dynamic async loading handle the dependency of one js file on another?

Comment: Is there any library which handles both CSS and JS dynamic loading?

Answer (score 0):

USE [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to solve the issue

Comment: Does that handle CSS and JS both?

Comment: Yes it handles both CSS and JS, more info here: http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html